# How to find all elements in Selenium by xpath and ignore their first part?

Tags: selenium, xpath, find, webdriver, element

For exampel those 3:

```
.//*[@id='stream-item-tweet-746838978284818432']/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]
.//*[@id='stream-item-tweet-746838891605397504']/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]
.//*[@id='stream-item-tweet-746838648461590528']/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]
```

The numbers are constantly changing on the website. Is there an option to search for those elements by xpath and ignore the long numbers in the middle?

Comment: It is better if the title of your question is also a question, so. Good luck!

Comment: can you show the html source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **contains** function of xpath
 
`.//*[contains(@id,'stream-item-tweet')]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ***starts-with*** function, this way you'll get only the elements with an **id** starting with whatever text you want

```
.//*[starts-with(@id,'stream-item-tweet-')]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using CSS selectors, you can you do this in a more straightforward way. Your XPath is somewhat fragile with all the relative elements. Below is working code in Java.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Tweet actions']"));
```

I'm sure this could be converted to an XPath, if you absolutely have to have one, but I'm not an XPath expert.